# Doing var=`cmd1 | cmd2` in shell

Tags: sh

Hi I'm trying to execute a command containing a | and capturing the output in Bourne Shell but I can't get it to work.

Additionally, I'd like to capture this command's output in an array so I tried

```
#!/bin/sh
rsl=($(cmd))
```

But I get an error with the first parenthesis.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Read your Bourne shell man page. You're not going to find any mention of arrays. If you want help with `var=\`cmd1 | cmd2\``, then you have to tell us more than "it's not working". Don't respond in comments, please improve your question. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The POSIX Bourne shell does not support arrays.

Consider using Bash, Ksh or another more advanced shell instead.